# I want to make a recyclerview that shows data to a new Activity from SQLITE database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a project, I have a sqlite database that has id, title, content
I want to make a recyclerview and get titles from database and set it to recyclerview items per position and when the user click on some item, they will be able to read the content from database. Hope my question is clear! Thank you.

Here is my DatabaseHelper class

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DBNAME = "alQais.db";

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

public DatabaseHelper(Context mContext){
    super(mContext, DBNAME, null, 1);
    this.context = mContext;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void openDatabase(){
    String dbPath = context.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if(sqLiteDatabase != null && sqLiteDatabase.isOpen()){
        return;
    }
    sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public void closeDatabase(){
    if(sqLiteDatabase != null){
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }
}

public ArrayList getAllTitles(){
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from muallaqat", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return arrayList;
}

public String getMuallaqa(String title){
    String muallaqat;
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from muallaqat where title like '" + title + "'", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    muallaqat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("muallaqa"));
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return muallaqat;
}}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
ListView listView;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    File database = getBaseContext().getDatabasePath(db.DBNAME);
    if(false == database.exists()){
        db.getReadableDatabase();
        if(copyDatabase(this)){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }

    ArrayList lstTitles = db.getAllTitles();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, lstTitles);


    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String title = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private boolean copyDatabase(Context mContext){
    try{
        InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(db.DBNAME);
        String outFileName = db.DBLOCATION + db.DBNAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0){
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}}
```

This is the activity that shows the content coming from sqlite

**Main2Activity.java**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Amiri-Regular.ttf");

    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

    final TextView muallaqa = findViewById(R.id.muallaqa);

    muallaqa.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    muallaqa.setTypeface(face);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    String fullMuallaqa = db.getMuallaqa(title);
    muallaqa.setText(fullMuallaqa);
    this.setTitle(title);
}}
```

Comment: Hi mugiwaranoluffy, can yout post the code of your recycler adapter?

Comment: @NestorPerez sure, I will update my post
I'm working with a listview rn but I want to work with a recyclerview + cardview

Answer (score 1):

> For Reference Follow Steps

1)create setter and getter methods for  id, title, content
for example

```
public class settter 
 {

int id;
String name;
String content;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
   }
 }
```

2)add recyclerview in xml mainactivity

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

3)In MainActivity remove all listview releated code and add code given below

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //make array list object with setter class
        ArrayList<setter> name =db.getAllTitles();

       //new adapter(ArrayList<setter>, context) ,so initiate adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new adapter(name,getApplicationContext()));

        //draw line 
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new 
     DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

4) create layout file which hold your data and inflate inside recyclerview

name: recycler_content_holder.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_content_holder"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv_id"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

5) Create Adapter class

```
public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.AdapterViewHolder>
{

ArrayList<settter> data;
Context context;
public adapter(ArrayList<settter> data,Context context)
{
    this.data=data;
    this.context=context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.recycler_content_holder,viewGroup,false);
    return new ProgramingViewHolder(view);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i)
{

    viewHolder.id.setText(""+data.get(i).getId());
    viewHolder.title.setText(data.get(i).getTitle());
    viewHolder.content.setText(data.get(i).getContent());

    viewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            String title = String.valueOf(data.get(i).getTitle());
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

//class programingViewHolder
public class AdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView id,title,content;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public AdapterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        id=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_mtrNo);
        content=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nm);
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_content_holder);

    }


  }
 }
```

6) change method in DatabaseHelper

```
public ArrayList<setter> getAllTitles(){
    ArrayList<setter> arrayList = new ArrayList();
    openDatabase();
    setter set=new setter();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from muallaqat", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        set.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
        //add object to arralist
        arrayList.add(set);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return arrayList;
}
```

Just Copy, paste and understand, I hope it will help you.

Comment: I've already found a solution and it's similar to yours! I'm working with a recyclerview now. I just had to make a model class that has setters and getters to get data from database. Thank you! :)

Comment: welcome, If you have any query related to recyclerview then inform me, it will be pleasure to help you.@mugiwaranoluffy

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to use a recyclerview with data from an SQLite database? and you want open a new activity when you click on an item and populate it with data from the item? Check out this article

[Implementation of RecyclerView with Cursor Adapter](https://androidwave.com/implementation-of-recyclerview-with-cursor-adapter/)

Answer (score 0):

Just Do one thing 
That Take id and title from database and show title in recyclerview. And When onItemClick on recyclerview pass the id of perticular position to next activity.

And In next activity fetch id which is passed from previous activity.

And fetch data from data with id. You will get all the data.

And show fetched data to activity.